# Check to see if a compiled dll has changed?

Tags: .net, deployment

We are trying to figure out a way to see if a dll on a user pc is different from the deployment server. We can't use a timestamp because our build script builds everything everytime (and this is the way we want to keep it). We also prefer not to use version # because we can definitely see people forgetting this a lot. Some of our dlls change all the time (at least a couple times a week). I tried to create an XML File with the MD5 hash of every file but apparently this won't work because the hash changes every time we compile it even if there was no changes. Is there any other way?

Comment: Why not implement automatic versioning done by your build server to eliminate the risk of people forgetting to set versions?

Comment: Anna wouldn't that mean each file would would be a new version each time you do a build since in our setup everything is built? That wouldn't work of course if thats true.

Comment: @user127954 Point. You could also evolve your build environment to only build what you need and use known versions for dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the DLLs produce different hashes, it's clear that something changes on each compile.  Perhaps something internal is timestamp-driven or randomized.

Theoretically it's probably possible using reflection or ildasm and some smart comparison of the results, but that would be a lot harder than revising your process to use incrementing version strings.

I suggest that you automate your build process and automatically increment the version string in assemblyinfo.cs each build.  If you are using source control, your build script could check it out, increment it, and check it back in.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I guess i was just hoping there was some utility out there that would do this but maybe not. I guess we will just have to require developers update the version number and go with that. 

The automated build part really isn't a solution unless it was really smart and knew exactly what changed and what it needed to compile. The only way i know to do that would be to create a different build script for each dll/exec then the order you need stuff to be built would be shot because they would be queued randomly

Answer (score 1):

I was recently asked to do a similar task and I used the [Reflector Diff AddIn](http://www.codingsanity.com/diff.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an incremental build number that gets included in some version string of your dll. Have you tried doing a diff on your dlls? If that is the case you may be able to "mask" the version string on the fly for the calculation of you md5 hash.